# Node.js/Express: Prevent AJAX HTML snippet from being loaded directly from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm building a blog with Node.js, Express and MongoDB.

On the home page I have a button to load more posts. This works fine and I accomplish it with the following code:

**jQuery**

```
$("#load-more-posts").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/load/posts/',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#primary").append(data);
        },
        data: {"passLastDate": lastDate}
    });

    return false;
});
```

Here's the route in **app.js**

```
app.get("/load/posts", routes.loadPosts);
```

And here's the view:

```
loadPosts: function(req, res) {
  var lastDate;
  lastDate = req.query.passLastDate;
  return Post.find({
    "published": true,
    "publish_date": {
      $lt: lastDate
    }
  }).sort('-publish_date').limit(1).execFind(function(err, posts) {
    if (posts === []) {
      console.log("thats it");
      return res.render("thats-it", {
        layout: false
      });
    } else {
      lastDate = posts.slice(-1)[0].publish_date;
      return res.render("more-posts", {
        layout: false,
        posts: posts,
        lastDate: lastDate
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Like I said, this all works great. However, if I copy the GET url from the console and paste it in the browser directly I get a returned HTML snippet. I suppose this is working like it should, but I don't want to return it. I don't think it's a security hazard, just seems a little inelegant.

**Is there a way to block a direct request to this view?**

**BONUS**

Here's something else that's strange, and makes this a two-part question. When I check for an empty post array in the `if` statement, Node ignores it. The console output shows `posts = []` yet it skips right over it and then an error is thrown on `lastDate = posts.slice(-1)[0].publish_date;` I know JS behaves funny with empty values (null, undefined, empty string, etc.) but I've tried different ones with the same result. It seems like it's ignoring it completely. Am I taking crazy pills?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to block a direct request to this view?

You could check and see if the request was performed using an AJAX call by checking for the `x-requested-with` header (which jQuery sends along):

```
loadPosts: function(req, res) {
  if (req.headers['x-requested-with'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    // AJAX request
  }
  else {
    // not an AJAX request
  }
}
```

This shouldn't be used as a security measure (because it's not) but only as a way of checking to see if the request was made using AJAX or not.

As for your other problem, `[] === []` is actually false (as is `[] == []`), so that's not a good way to see if an array is empty. I'd suggest you use:

```
if (!posts || posts.length === 0) {
  // empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a session (which is initialized in the main page) to protect your snippets.
Add a middle-ware before the route to the snippets, the middle-ware checks the session token and redirects if no session is found.
It's pretty much the same as a system with data protected by login, and your main page login automatically for each user.

I can fetch some examples for you, leave a comment if you need it.

[BONUS]

Have you tried <strike>`posts == []` or</strike> `posts.length === 0` instead of `posts === []`?

Comment: You have to use `posts.length === 0`, `posts == []` didn't work. Thanks!